# use ref with mapStateToProps doesn't work reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I try to call a child function with ref, but child function have a reduce function, so it does'nt work :

my parent :

```
search(data) {
    this.SearchProduct.search(data);
}
...
<SearchProduct ref={instance => { this.SearchProduct = instance; }} />
```

My child :

```
class SearchProduct extends React.Component {
...

    search(data) {
       console.log(data)
    }
...
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
    basket: state.basket,
});


const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({

    setBasket: (basket) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_BASKET', basket });
    }
});

module.exports = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps,
    null,
    { withRef: true }
)(SearchProduct);
```

When i fire :

```
component.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: this.SearchProduct.search is not a function
```

Any one have an idea ?

Thank's a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to get wrapped instance like this

```
search(data) {
    this.SearchProduct.getWrappedInstance().search(data);
}
```

[Docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#getwrappedinstance-reactcomponent).